# Best/Correct way to add an option to a category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, database

I'm currently writing my first plugin, which will let the site admin/editor use a different image as a background/header for each post/page, and I would also like to have defaults for each category.

Here is where I'm not sure how to proceed: If for each post/page the image (which is an attachment, so is just an id in the db) is a simple post meta field, there is no such (implicit) thing for categories.

So there are more ways to go:

- Create an option for every category - something like `background_cat_$id_`
- Add the categories which correspond to a certain image to the attachment post ( `corresponding_cats` ? )
- Modify the term_taxonomy table to add a column (last resort? bad design?)

Right now I believe I'll go with my first option but I'm really curios how you handle such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-term-meta/

Comment: that seems to do everything I wanted to do. Is it any other way to mark it as a dependency other than writing in the README or using your dependency plugin?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the approach I use myself in my answer [to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/category-listing-with-thumbnail-and-description-on-home-page/6817#6817)

You're on the right track though. Until we have a taxonomy meta table then the options table is the tidiest solution. You could always create a taxonomy meta table yourself with the plugin though and make some get/set functions to go with it.

Comment: Your other answer seems really insightful and helps me with some other questions I had, but I'm still interested in some other points of view so I won't accept your answer quite yet :)

Comment: np. I'd be interested to see if anyone has implemented a taxonomy meta table myself. Seems like a worthy plugin to write. Hopefully my next project at work will cover the dev time.